# Exchange 2010 Delegate vs Full Access Permissions

Tags: permissions, exchange-2010, resources

I'm wondering if anyone can help clarify how permissions work on rooms in Exchange. Specifically, we've got a room setup in Exchange, I have assigned users under the 'Resource Policy' tab as delegates. When I run the powershell comand 'Get-MailboxFolderPermission alias:\Calendar', it lists all the delegates as having 'Editor' permissions. However, none of the delegates can create an appointment directly on the calendar which they would like to do. It seems to me that an editor ought to be able to add an appointment directly to the calendar, but when they try, it says 'Could not save item. Cannot open the free/busy information. You do not have sufficient permission...'

I think maybe I'm missing something about how the delegate/editor permissions work, and I'm wondering, under what instances would I add the user with 'Full Access Permission' vs adding them as a delegate with 'Editor' permissions. In this instance, these users will be scheduling rooms that we rent out rather than scheduling a meeting (scheduling a meeting puts it on their calendar as well which they don't want).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.